# Slow CPU processing when windows update is pending

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, windows-update, windows-server

We have 40ish laptops that are quite old with a few newer laptops, my family has older laptops and I have a fairly good laptop, we also have 2 servers windows-2016 and windows-2019.

On all of these devices I have noticed that when a windows update is pending, please note pending not installing, pending not downloading, everything runs slower.  It has become so obvious, that if one of our users comes to us with a weird problem, we tell them to check for updates.

Sometimes they will go to updates and there they are waiting to be installed, sometimes they have to click the check for updates, and then there they are and they start downloading.  Often they say, but I checked them last week.

The better spec'd the computer the less noticeable the problem is, on my own laptop I generally notice a slowing, check for update there they are.  Install them and away we go again.  Same thing on both our servers, CPU monitor alerts get triggered, users complain our site is slow.  So I go to the server, install the update (security ones that we haven't found a way to stop from getting through), and away we go again.

I've had friends complain that their computers are slow, same thing, check for updates.

I've updated my laptop to Windows 11, and paused updates.  I noticed my windows button wasn't responding as quickly as normal, so I started updates again, there we have it an update.  So pausing updates doesn't seem to pause them from hiding in the background pending.

I know what you are saying it is the reboot after the update that is getting the speed boost, but some updates don't require a reboot.  On our SQL server it is plainly obvious, it goes from 70% cpu to 100% cpu when an update is pending.  Then back to 70% after it is installed, often it is a security update which doesn't require a reboot.

I can't seem to find any thing on the internet about it, but surely I can't be the only person experiencing this?

Throwing hardware at it, controlling the updates are all just Band-Aids I am looking for a fix.  I can't see why a computer that runs OK, can't continue to run OK when it has been notified that an update is available to be downloaded.

Has anyone experienced this and solved the issue?

Update:
Just got off a call from Microsoft, and the person confirmed that even when updates are turned off the computer still gets informed that an update is present, it just won't download or install or notify.  Which confirms my experience with my Windows 11.

Comment: On my system, Windows Updates are not doing anything (sitting in Optional) or if not Optional and go a Pending state, they start downloading. I would check this carefully. On an older machine with a slow hard drive, this can take resources.  Alternately they are pending doing nothing if waiting for other update downloads and install.

Comment: Dou you have a WSUS server in your network? Windows is able to share updates in some sort of peer-to-peer system.  If updates are waiting for installation that have already been downloaded clients may share the updates and cause this system behavior. I would monitor CPU and Ethernet in such a situation.

Comment: @Robert these are not just networked computers, these are personal computers.  Some are connected to Azure AD, some are just friends and family's, not connected to any network, lots with different internet providers.  All in New Zealand so maybe it is just an issues for one country, but that seems odd.  The whole thing seems odd.

Comment: @John I can assure you they are not downloading nor installing, that I can completely understand.  Note that on my Windows 11, updates were turned off.  See my edit above for a confirmation from Microsoft in releation to that.

Comment: @Robert also they haven't downloaded the update yet, so I doubt there is anything to share.

Comment: I have not seen this. Hundreds of customer computers. Something strange, some software installed, I am not certain but I have not seen this.

Comment: @John it may be not noticed rather than not seen.  :-)

Now you know you might see, most people don't believe me, until I've told them then they start noticing it.

Comment: Still happening on Windows 10 Enterprise 21H1

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm OP's experience.

Whenever I get updates alerts, the overall performance suffers for as long as the updates are not installed. The CPU usage spikes to well over 90%, even after a Sleep or Hybernation.

After the update is installed everything runs smoothly again.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1106523)

Comment: Thanks for the confirm.